# Scanners interacting between methods/main()

Tags: java

When I compile the code I get this error:

```
    AuthoringAssistant.java:19: error: cannot find symbol
    char menuChoice = printMenu(scan);
                              ^
    symbol:   variable scan
    location: class AuthoringAssistant
    1 error
```

I've only just started learning Java this semester so I'm still trying to get the hang of methods, and I'm really confused right now by how scanners interact between methods and main(). If someone could point me in the right direction that would be a big help since I have to write about 5 more methods to cram into this thing.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class AuthoringAssistant {

public static String scnrMethod() {

  Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);
  String userInput = scnr.nextLine(); // userInput scans for text
  return userInput;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {      

  System.out.println("Enter a sample text:");
  scnrMethod();
  System.out.println();
  System.out.println("You entered: " + scnrMethod());

  char menuChoice = printMenu(scan);

  boolean t = true;

  if (menuChoice == 'q') {
     System.exit(0);
  }
  //else if (menuChoice == 'c') {
  //   System.out.println();
  //}
  //else if (menuChoice == 'w') {
  //   System.out.println();
  //}
  //else if (menuChoice == 'f') {
  //   System.out.println();
  //}
  //else if (menuChoice == 'r') {
  //   System.out.println();
  //}
  //else if (menuChoice == 's') {
  //   System.out.println();
  //}
  else {
     t = false;
  }
  if (t != true) {
    System.out.print("Input an option: " + menuChoice);
  }

}

public static char printMenu(Scanner scan) {//provides menu for main() 

  System.out.println();
  System.out.println("MENU");
  System.out.println("c - Number of non-whitespace characters");
  System.out.println("w - Number of words");
  System.out.println("f - Find text");
  System.out.println("r - Replace all !'s");
  System.out.println("s - Shorten spaces");
  System.out.println("q - Quit\n");

  System.out.println("Choose an option:");
  char menuChoice = scan.nextLine().charAt(0);

  return menuChoice;      
} 

//public static int getNumOfNonWSCharacters() { //finds number of non-
//whitespace characters in the text
//   
//   
//   return ;
//}

}
```

Comment: What is `scan`?

Comment: You need to declare the variable `scan` before your method-call. In this case it would be: `Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);`

Comment: @Frederik Hansen when I do that it throws: 
`Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line found
 at java.util.Scanner.nextLine(Scanner.java:1540)
 at AuthoringAssistant.scnrMethod(AuthoringAssistant.java:8)
 at AuthoringAssistant.main(AuthoringAssistant.java:18)`

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/NoSuchElementException.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing a variable declaration. Since you're using your `Scanner` multiple places I would suggest to make the same instance available to these methods.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class AuthoringAssistant {

    private static Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static String scnrMethod() {
        String userInput = scan.nextLine(); // userInput scans for text
        return userInput;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Enter a sample text:");
        String input = scnrMethod();
        System.out.println("You entered: " + input);

        char menuChoice = printMenu();

        boolean t = true;

        if (menuChoice == 'q') {
            System.exit(0);
        }
        else {
            t = false;
        }
        if (t != true) {
            System.out.print("Input an option: " + menuChoice);
        }

    }

    public static char printMenu() {// provides menu for main()

        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("MENU");
        System.out.println("c - Number of non-whitespace characters");
        System.out.println("w - Number of words");
        System.out.println("f - Find text");
        System.out.println("r - Replace all !'s");
        System.out.println("s - Shorten spaces");
        System.out.println("q - Quit\n");

        System.out.println("Choose an option:");
        char menuChoice = scan.nextLine().charAt(0);

        return menuChoice;
    }

}
```